# End chat session and restart new dialog at the end of a session

Tags: c#, botframework

I have a Maindialog with a CompleteAsync Function that is firing when the child dialog is calling `stepContext.EndDialogAsync();`

```cs
protected override async Task CompleteAsync(DialogContext dc, DialogTurnResult result = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {            
        await _responder.ReplyWith(dc.Context, MainResponses.ResponseIds.NewUserGreeting);
        await dc.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(ProductFlowDialog));
    }
```

When it 's firing, the initial step of the waterfall of the child dialog is never called.
To temporarily fix the issue, I have moved the  `await dc.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(ProductFlowDialog))` call into the routeAsync function.

```cs
  protected override async Task CompleteAsync(DialogContext dc, DialogTurnResult result = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        await _responder.ReplyWith(dc.Context, MainResponses.ResponseIds.Completed);         
    }
```

```cs
 protected override async Task RouteAsync(DialogContext dc, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        _responder = new MainResponses();
        await _responder.ReplyWith(dc.Context, MainResponses.ResponseIds.NewUserGreeting);
        await dc.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(ProductFlowDialog));       
    }
```

The problem with this solution is that the end user has to type something in the chat to reinitiate the dialogflow.
I want to automatically restart a new dialog flow when the dialog flow ends.

Comment: what do you mean by initial step of the waterfall of the child, are you getting any error here?

Comment: the first function supposed to be called in the dialog doesn't fire. It does fire correctly  the first time the chat starts or with the current workaround.

Comment: Is it skipping the step? Or your dialog is ending completely? I had an issue where my first step prompt was being skipped in some conditions, and it was due to incorrectly calling continueDialog in my main bot dialog logic.

Comment: we restarted the dvt from scratch with another bot template and the issue doesn't occur anymore. Absolutely no idea where it came from

Answer (score 0):

we restarted the dvt from scratch with another bot template and the issue doesn't occur anymore. Absolutely no idea where it came from